# PortAudio real-time audio processing for continuous input stream

Tags: c, data-structures, boost-thread, portaudio, circular-buffer

I am using PortAudio to implement a real-time audio processing.

My primary task is to acquire data from mic continuously and provide 100 samples for processing `(each FRAME = 100 samples at a time)` to some other processing thread.

Here is my **callback** collecting 100 samples each time on a continuous basis -

```
static int paStreamCallback( const void* input, void* output,
    unsigned long samplesPerFrame,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void* userData ) {

    paTestData *data = (paTestData*) userData;
    const SAMPLE *readPtr = (const SAMPLE*)input;   // Casting input read to valid input type SAMPLE (float)
    unsigned long totalSamples = TOTAL_NUM_OF_SAMPLES ; // totalSamples = 100 here

    (void) output;
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;

    static int count = 1;

    if(data->sampleIndex < count * samplesPerFrame){
        data->recordedSample[data->sampleIndex] = *readPtr;
        data->sampleIndex++;
    }

    else if(data->sampleIndex ==  count * samplesPerFrame){

        processSampleFrame(data->recordedSample);
        count++;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    return finished;
}
```

My `**main** function -

```
int main(void){

// Some Code here

data.sampleIndex = 0;
data.frameIndex = 1;

numBytes = TOTAL_NUM_OF_SAMPLES * sizeof(SAMPLE);
data.recordedSample = (SAMPLE*)malloc(numBytes);

for(i=0; i < TOTAL_NUM_OF_SAMPLES; i++)
    data.recordedSample[i] = 0;

// Open Stream Initialization

err = Pa_StartStream(stream);

/* Recording audio here..Speak into the MIC */
printf("\nRecording...\n");
fflush(stdout);

while((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1)
    Pa_Sleep(10);

    if(err < 0)
            goto done;

    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);

// Some more code here
}
```

Sending each Frame of 100 samples to processSampleFrame.

```
void processSampleFrame(SAMPLE *singleFrame){

    // Free buffer of this frame
    // Processing sample frame here
}
```

The challenge is that I need to implement a way in which the time `processSampleFrame` is processing the samples, my `callBack` should be active and keep acquiring the next `Frame of 100 samples` and (may be more depending upon the processing time of `processSampleFrame`).

Also the buffer should able to free itself of the frame so sooner it has passed it to `processSampleFrame`.

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried implementing with `PaUtilRingBuffer` that `PortAudio` provides. Here is my **callback**.

```
printf("Inside callback\n");
paTestData *data = (paTestData*) userData;

ring_buffer_size_t elementsWritable = PaUtil_GetRingBufferWriteAvailable(&data->ringBuffer);
ring_buffer_size_t elementsToWrite = rbs_min(elementsWritable, (ring_buffer_size_t)(samplesPerFrame * numChannels));

const SAMPLE *readPtr = (const SAMPLE*)input;
printf("Sample ReadPtr = %.8f\n", *readPtr);
(void) output;      // Preventing unused variable warnings
(void) timeInfo;
(void) statusFlags;

data->frameIndex += PaUtil_WriteRingBuffer(&data->ringBuffer, readPtr, elementsToWrite);

return paContinue;
```

And **main** :

```
int main(void){

    paTestData data;    // Object of paTestData structure

    fflush(stdout);

    data.frameIndex = 1;

    long numBytes = TOTAL_NUM_OF_SAMPLES * LIMIT;
    data.ringBufferData = (SAMPLE*)PaUtil_AllocateMemory(numBytes);
    if(PaUtil_InitializeRingBuffer(&data.ringBuffer, sizeof(SAMPLE), ELEMENTS_TO_WRITE, data.ringBufferData) < 0){
        printf("Failed to initialise Ring Buffer.\n");
        goto done;

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);

    /* Recording audio here..Speak into the MIC */
    printf("\nRecording samples\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1)
        Pa_Sleep(10);

    if(err < 0)
                goto done;

        err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);

    // Error Handling here
}
```

`PaTestData` Structure :

```
typedef struct{

    SAMPLE *ringBufferData;
    PaUtilRingBuffer ringBuffer;    
    unsigned int frameIndex;
}
paTestData;
```

I am facing the same issue of seg-fault after successful acquisition for the allocated space because of not being able to use any `free` in the `callback` as suggested by `PortAudio` documentation.

Where can I free the buffer of the allocated frame given to the processing thread. May be a method of obtaining a thread-synchronization can be really useful here. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the consumer of `/tmp/fifoPipe`? `open(fifoPipe, O_WRONLY);` will block until the pipe is opened for reading, which may be causing your data loss. Also, do you really want to create and open a fifo for every sample? Shouldn't the fifo only be created and opened once?

Comment: @Tim , the consumer is another thread which is not mentioned here. I have shown here the producer putting each frames to PIPE. I want to create a non-blocking system, and hence I have taken an approach using ring buffers. Please suggest if I could proceed with anything else?

Comment: Why send this to another thread? Can you not process the data in the callback?

Comment: @yun.cloud If I process in callback, I will lose some data during that time

Comment: Weird I've never encountered a loss of data (at least severe enough) that it affected performance. What are you specifically trying to do? How does it sound when it's just straight audio input -> audio output? Also circular buffers!

Comment: @yun.cloud Actually I am trying to create a system that will continuously listen for audio signals and send 100 samples to a processing thread (the thread has an algo that is detecting for a hotword). I cannot stop listening for the time the previous frame is being processed. I really need help regarding any way that would help me do the same.

Comment: I am open to write everything back from scratch if you can suggest me any better way to do this.

Comment: @yun.cloud  I had implemented using `PaUtilRingBuffer`, but then Don't know how do I `freeBuffer` everytime. I know the `PaUtil_InitialiseRingBuffer` does a `PaUtil_FlushRingBuffer` which will enable storage of another frame but not sure whether I could initialise my ring Buffer inside callback. I will edit the code if you want to look at it.

Comment: @yun.cloud I have edited the question

Comment: I think you should approach this problem as such: Have a fixed circular buffer with a size 4x (or bigger, 4 is arbitrary) the number of samples you're reading per callback (we'll call this size FRAMES). Read in size FRAMES per callback and send data to your separate thread/algorithm to process. At the end of the callback, increment your write index by FRAMES. This will create latency but it's pretty much unavoidable in a real time system. I would search up FFTs and pitch shifting algorithms from Stanford to understand how to process a chunk of data without losing anything.

Comment: @yun.cloud The send data to the thread would be in the callback itself? And I don't need to free buffer (as in will it be overwriting in the next acquisition after the limit 4 FRAMES you suggested)?

Comment: @yun.cloud also if you could suggest me some good reading/tutorial on PortAudio, it would be a great help.

Comment: Yes; I personally have never done it where I would have to send the data in another thread. I'll post an "example" in the answers to kind of show what I'm talking about. AND you should never allocate/free memory in a callback! This screws up things in a callback because it delays the system since it needs to reallocate memory. And sorry I pretty much learned a bunch of this stuff by myself :(

Comment: I think I am kind of in a same situation, trying and learning things by myself. As of now I have been able to do this reading the documentations portaudio provides but would really appreciate examples for a better understanding. Thankyou so much @yun.cloud for your support!

Comment: And I think I pretty much got to know what is going wrong when I am sending data to another thread, I would better design the processing thread to use data directly from the ring buffer and increment pointer (by Frame size) rightaway. Waiting for your example anyway :)

Comment: Yea no problem be sure to browse through the portaudio mailing list as well; this stuff definitely has a learning curve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example code of processing audio input:

```
#define FRAME_SIZE                 1024
#define CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE       (FRAME_SIZE * 4)

float buffer[CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE];

typedef struct {
     int read, write;
     float vol;
} paData;

static int paStreamCallback(const void* input, void* output,
                            unsigned long samplesPerFrame,
                            const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                            PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                            void* userData) {

    paData *data = (paData *)userData;
    // Write input buffer to our buffer: (memcpy function is fine, just a for loop of writing data
    memcpy(&buffer[write], input, samplesPerFrame); // Assuming samplesPerFrame = FRAME_SIZE

    // Increment write/wraparound
    write = (write + FRAME_SIZE) % CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE;

    // dummy algorithm for processing blocks:
    processAlgorithm(&buffer[read]);

    // Write output
    float *dummy_buffer = &buffer[read]; // just for easy increment
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesPerFrame; i++) {
         // Mix audio input and processed input; 50% mix
         output[i] = input[i] * 0.5 + dummy_buffer[i] * 0.5;
    }

    // Increment read/wraparound
    read = (read + FRAME_SIZE) % CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE;

    return paContinue;
}

int main(void) {
     // Initialize code here; any memory allocation needs to be done here! default buffers to 0 (silence)
     // initialize paData too; write = 0, read = 3072
     // read is 3072 because I'm thinking about this like a delay system.
}
```

Take this with a grain of salt; Obviously better ways of doing this but it can be used as a starting point.

Comment: This seems to be wonderful. One last quick question before I proceed with what you suggested. Shall I use normal circular buffer rather than the bit complex PaUtilBuffer API that PortAudio provides, i mean any performance gap?

Comment: Hm honestly never really looked into it; PaUtilBuffer might be better but the way I was "initially" taught was to make your own buffer. If you don't understand how a certain thing works in API then I think it's better to either research it until you understand it or implement something you can understand.